# How get modular page processed content

Tags: php, twig, grav

I created a plugin with the createIndexData function:

```
public static function createIndexData($file): bool
{
    $pages = self::getPages();
    $grav = Grav::instance();
    if($pages !== null){
        $locator = $grav['locator'];
        $grav['twig']->twig_paths[]= array_merge(Grav::instance()['twig']->twig_paths, $locator->findResources('theme://templates'));
        $grav->fireEvent('onTwigTemplatePaths');

        $page = $pages->find('/austria/_price-list');
        /*dump($page);*/
        dump($page->content());
        exit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The plugin is called in onPagesInitialized. I just need to get the processed content from the modular page. In the modular page, I include content from another page: (/pages/austria/_price-list)

```
{% set moduleName= 'price-list' %} 
{% set pageUrl = page.find(uri.path).rawRoute[1:] %} 
{% set pageUrl = '/global-variables-and-templates/price-list/data/_austria' %} 
{% set page = page.find(pageUrl) %} 
{% if not page %} 
   PAGE NOT EXIST!!!!<br />url: {{pageUrl}}<br />modul-name: {{moduleName}} 
{% else %}
    {% include page.template~'.html.twig' with {'content' : page.content} %} 
{% endif %}
```

plugin returns error: Template "modular/price-list-global.html.twig" is not defined. What is wrong? Or how to get the processed content from the modular page in grav in the custom plugin?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is unclear to me and you might be going into the wrong direction. You might want to consider editing your question to add some clarity.

Comment: I need to get the content of a modular page. I need to get the content of a modular page that is processed (twig). When I call $page->content(), during processing "include page" an error is displayed: Template "xyz" is not defined

Comment: Repeating the question in one sentence doesn't make it more clear... 1) Where do you need the content of the module? In PHP or Twig? About PHP snippet: 2) What are you trying to achieve with function 'createIndexData($file)'? 3) Code seems messy, please only show correct code. 4) Where is required template created? In theme or current plugin? 5) Why is event being fired? About Twig snippet: 6) You are shadowing variable 'page' which is considered not done.. 7) Why are you including the template of the page to be included? 8) ...

Answer (score -1):

solution for plugin error: Template "modular/some-template.html.twig" is not defined
add to function:

```
$grav = Grav::instance();
$grav['twig']->twig_paths[]= __DIR__ .'/../../../themes/yourtheme/templates';
```

Comment: If template is defined in theme, there is no need to add it to Twig's paths. If you need a hardcoded path, you need to scratch your head...